# ubuntu イメージを docker-compose で起動して UP 状態にしたい

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Dockerfiles/rails/Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

docker-compose.yml

```
rails:
    build: Dockerfiles/rails/
    image: rails
    container_name: rails
    ports:
     - "3003:3000"
    links:
     - mysql
    networks:
      rails_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2
    restart: always
```

を作成して `docker-compose up -d` を実行したところ
docker ps で STATUS が UP にならずに
`Restarting (1) 29 seconds ago`
が繰り返されます

UP 状態にして中に `docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash` で入りたいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか

`ubuntu:14.04` を `mysql:5.6` にかえると起動したままになります

Comment: [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38546755/4506703)が参考になりそうですがどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　うまくUPにできました！

Comment: @KTI 解決したようであれば、自己回答の形でまとめていただけると他のユーザーの助けになると思います。

Comment: １度は起動したのですがそれ以降何の変更もしてないのに再起動を繰り返すようになってもう一人で解決できなさそうなので docker を使うのを諦めました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで教えていただいた通り
`tty: true` 
で起動状態を維持できるようになりました

ただその状態でPC(ホスト)を再起動するとコンテナが落ちてしまうんですが
社内の他の人が作ったコンテナはそれでもずっと起動し続けてるので
できればその方法を知りたかったのですが

毎回 docker-compose up すればPC落とすまでは起動できるようになったので
これでやりたいことはできました